# How do I drag, drop and scale an image in a div and maintain the same large size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working on a new project that requires me to drag elements from a div on the left and drop them to a div on the right. When they get to the right side they need to increase in size and stay that way until clicked. The dragging and dropping is working fine, but I can't seem to get the images to keep the new larger size.

I tried changing my class with javascript when it's dropped into said div and am currently trying to apply a transition with a duration of 9999s to pull off what I'm looking to do.

Is there a better way of doing this? I have to imagine there is.

Here's the code I'm working with now.

**Html**

```
<div class="grow" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<img id="drag1" src="img/mountains.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
```

**Javascript**

```
 function allowDrop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();

}
function drag(ev){
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("content", ev.target.id);
}
function drop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var image= ev.dataTransfer.getData("content");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(image));

}
```

**CSS**

```
#div1 {
width:500px;
height:200px;
padding:10px;
border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
/* 2D TRANSITIONS */
/* Grow */
.grow {
display: inline-block;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
transition-duration: 0.3s; 
-webkit-transition-duration: 9999s;
-webkit-transition-property: transform;
transition-property: transform;
transform: translateZ(0);
box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.grow:hover, .grow:focus, .grow:active {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1); 
transform: scale(1.9);
}
```

Comment: Impossible to know what you are talking about without some actual code. Make a small example and post it on JSFiddle or something similar.

Comment: Post the relevant code and even better create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Sorry I was in the middle of posting the code when I accidentally posted my question first.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle for this? I'm not exactly sure what you want. Your question mentions moving the image from one div to another, although your image is not in a div and you only have 1 div.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery to handle your mouseup event (the end of your drop), and then put in a callback to handle the increase in size but either using animate, or by using addClass to add a premade class with the new dimensions.

```
 $('#drag1').mousemove( function() {
      // make sure you bind the mouseup after the mousemove has occured
      $('#drag1').mouseup( function(){
           $(this).animate({width: '+=100', height: '+=100'}); // or whatever you want.
      });
 });
```

unless Ive totally misunderstood youre question of course

Comment: What do you mean when you say bound the mouseup? I've been toying with this code, but I don't know exactly know where to declare this.

Comment: I just mean that you need to bind the mouseup listener once the move handler has been activated, so it only fires if mousemove is in progress